# .tar.Z : no such file or directory When I try to JAR a file .. Why?

Tags: linux, scripting, solaris

In my code I am creating 2 folders. One as a folder to store archives, the other one is a folder inside the archive that will have tar, compressed and Jar compleated to it.

Why when it gets to the jar command it says .tar.Z no such file or directory ??

```
 #!/bin/bash

 echo "++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
 #The script should prompt the user for the name of a folder to archive.
 echo "Please enter the name of a folder to archive"
 read file1


 echo "++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
 #The script should prompt the user for the name of a folder to store the archives in.
 echo "Please enter a foldername to store archives in"
 read file2


 echo "++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
 #The script should create the folder input in step 2.
 mkdir $file2
 cd $file2
 mkdir $file1
 echo "Created Files"

 echo "++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
 #The script should run the command to TAR all of the files in the folder specified in step 1 to a tar archive called [folder name].tar in the archive folder specified in step 2.
 tar cf $file1.tar $file1


 echo "++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
 #The script should compress the TAR file you created in step 4 to a [folder name].tar.Z in the archive folder specified in step 2.
 compress -v $file1.tar


 echo "++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
 #The script should run the command to JAR all of the files in the folder specified in      step 1 to a jar archive called [folder name].jar in the archive folder specified in step 2.
 jar cf $ffile1.jar $ffile1.tar.Z
```

echo "++++++++++++++++++++++++++"

Answer (score 3):

You write `$ffile1.tar.Z` instead of `$file1.tar.Z`.